# How do I get string value of a parameter in to create key for a hash Javascript

Tags: javascript, hash

How do I get "my_param" as a string so that I can use it as a key in the has I am trying to create?

```
var my_function = function(my_param) {
  var my_hash = { 
    my_param: "foobar"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use bracket notation:

```
var my_hash = {};
my_hash[my_param] = "foobar";
```

Comment: +1 for keeping the OP's double quotes intact. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var my_hash = {};
my_hash[my_param] = 'foobar';
```

This is bracket notation, where `a.b = 'c'` is the same as `a['b'] = 'c'`.

Comment: I was 13 seconds earlier but my Internet connection broke the moment I hit submit. Writing this comment on my iPhone. Sucks to be me.

Comment: There really is no sense in fighting it. My answer simply blows yours out of the water.

Comment: @BoltClock - He made a ninja edit a few minutes in. His extra sentence may put him over the top though.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Ah yeah, that. Saw it too.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Hehe, ninja edit. I like that!

Comment: @BoltClock I hate typing code on iPhone/iPad. So I don't do it. :)

Comment: @alex: I mean I was doing it on my desktop, then it disconnected so my submit never got through.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm sure you can handle 10 less rep :P